# how to trigger a interrupt in mips and arm

Tags: assembly, arm, mips, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I can trigger an interrupt using this command in x86_64

```
asm volatile("int $236");
```

what is the equivalent in mips and arm if I want to trigger a interrupt in a linux embedded board?

Comment: Arm has a `SWI` instruction, mips probably has similar.

Comment: could you give me a asm example to trigger interrupt @Colin__s

Comment: https://www.heyrick.co.uk/armwiki/SWI